# Change in one item in list need to change total list items

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview, in that listview I have two textviews on every list item(to change units of list from one to other).when I click on perticular textview on item, need to change total list to related text units(here I am showing changing text color when clicked) but, when I click on text on item,total list willnot updated.How can it possible please help me.

Comment: We cannot help you unless you share your code with us :)

Comment: have  you used notifyDatasetChanged of listview ? @Umashankar

Comment: I need make a change on one item in list ,total list get get that change.How is it possible

Comment: where I use notifyDatasetChanged

Comment: you have to post your code

Comment: @UmashankarB you set array list in your listview and you have to update the arraylist item which you want. after that just call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` for your listview adapter.